# docker-compose up dumps several days' worth of logs to stdout

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-logs

I have an EC2 instance running a dockerized application using docker-compose.

Every time I run `docker-compose up`, many days' worth of logs to stdout for all services. This means that I have to wait up to an hour before all the logs have been printed and I start seeing recent logs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the old containers created by docker-compose are re-used.
Starting with `docker-compose up --force-recreate` should do the trick.

Though I remember this from the past, and for me, this problem no longer happens. So it could also be something else.

Please make sure the following:

1. You are using a modern version of docker-compose (I am running 1.29, run `docker-compose version`)
2. Please make sure the containers you are starting to are not already running (`docker-compose ps`), as then you will attach to them instead of starting them and then printing all the logs in the container is common.